# Migrate data to Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

How to migrate data from Azure file storage to Azure SQL DB

Error I am getting
Error 40615: Cannot connect to < servername

Comment: Refer this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/troubleshoot-common-errors-issues?view=azuresql#cannot-connect-to-server-due-to-firewall-issues)

Comment: @Aswin thanks for your response but I already referred this document

Comment: Okay. Is it resolved ? What are all the steps you did to resolve?

Comment: @Aswin not yet resolved

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings? Check if IP address is connected to the machine where ADF is running

Comment: can you provide more information on what you are exactly trying and error you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I tried to repro this and got the error `40615: Cannot open server`
  [image]
- Check the connection strings - server name, password, and database name.
- Add your client ip to the firewall. Below are the steps.

  1. Open the Azure SQL Database in azure portal.
  2. Click Networking

[image]

3. Click +Add a firewall rule
4. Add the client ip address.
5. You can also check allow azure services and resources to access this server. This will allow all azure resources to access your database.

[image]

Reference: MS Document on [IP firewall rules - Azure SQL Database and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure?view=azuresql#manage-firewall-rules-using-the-azure-portal)

Comment: Thank you issue resolved now I want to send email alert but I didn't find that in adf